# WriteProcessMemory std::vector<any> custom any class

Tags: c++, c++17

How would i use Write Process Memory with a std::vector

This works if i use std::vector

Im not sure if this any class is returning right info when using .Data()

```
class any
{
private:
    struct base {
        virtual ~base() {}
        virtual base* clone() const = 0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct data : base {
        data(T const& value) : value_(value) {}
        base* clone() const { return new data<T>(*this); }
        T value_;
    };
    base* ptr_;
public:
    template <typename T> any(T const& value) : ptr_(new data<T>(value)) {}
    any(any const& other) : ptr_(other.ptr_->clone()) {}
    any& operator= (any const& other) {
        any(other).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    ~any() { delete this->ptr_; }
    void swap(any& other) { std::swap(this->ptr_, other.ptr_); }

    template <typename T>
    T& get() {
        return dynamic_cast<data<T>&>(*this->ptr_).value_;
    }
};

template<typename T>
size_t vectorsizeof(const typename std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    return sizeof(T) * vec.size();
}

std::vector<any> args{100, 1.1f};
WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pMemory, args.data(), vectorsizeof(args), nullptr)
```

Comment: This -> `std::any_cast<LPVOID>(your_instance_of_any_goes_here)`.

Comment: @Ruks that does not work if the any item is not LPVOID, and i need a way to auto do it so i can still use `args.data()`

Comment: You need a way to *know* if the `std::any` type is holding an `LPVOID` object. The class doesn't share the type it is currently holding. Try making a scoped enum type or something similar to keep track of what it is currently holding or use an `std::variant` if it suits your problem.

Comment: Well, `std::any` does store the type it's currently holding. It is theoretically possible if `std::any` stored the size of the object it's currently holding, and implemented a type conversion to a `void *`, as a special case, then something like this would be possible. But it doesn't, so it's not possible. `std::any` does not work this way. You will have to find some other way to do what you want.

Comment: Besides, you do realize that any `std::any` can store any object, and different `std::any`s can store different objects of different sizes? So, in your vector of `std::any`s, each individual one of them can have a different actual size, so can you explain how you expect multiplying a `sizeof` of something (doesn't matter what) by the number of values in the vector, give you an accurate byte count? If you take a moment to think about this you should realize why this approach is fundamentally, and irrevocably, flawed, and cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 2):

> There has to be a easy way to use std::any in a vector with Write Process Memory.

No, there does not.

Ignoring what `std::any` does with the value it stores for the moment, `std::any` stores its value (as if) indirectly. This means that it is rather like a `vector<T>`; it stores a pointer to the object which it allocated on the heap (except the `T` is hidden from the type and it only stores one of them). So copying the bits of the `any` itself will *not* (necessarily) make the `T` it stores visible; you are (may be) copying a pointer, not what it points to.

Furthermore, `any` *can't* be delivered across processes like this, for many reasons. Even if you could get access to the byte-range of the object being stored by an `any`, you wouldn't be able to use that to reconstruct the `any` on the other side. And even if you somehow could, you'd somehow have to transmit the `type_index` that represents the type stored in the `any`. And *that* isn't cross-process compatible; a type index value for a particular type in one process can be different from the index for the same type in the other process.

What you want simply isn't going to work. You'll have to use something else, and that something else is going to have to have some knowledge of the type of data it's transmitting.

Comment: @werico4026: The fact that it's your implementation of the same type changes nothing about how possible what you're trying to do is. It doesn't even change the reasons why it's not possible (save the `type_index` part).